# Evaluation order of Union function in scala

Tags: scala, recursion

I am having a difficult time understanding the following function and why it works.

```
def union(other:IntSet): IntSet =
  ((left union right) union other) incl elem
```

where there are two cases of IntSets, a NonEmpty and an Empty:

```
class Empty:
  def union(other: IntSet) = other
  def incl(x: Int) = new NonEmpty(elem, new Empty, new Empty)

class NonEmpty(elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet):
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = {
    if(x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left incl x, right
    else if(x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right incl x)
    else this
}
```

Given two trees like:

1)

```
         2
        / \
       1   3
```

and 2)

```
         5
        / \
       3   6
```

How would the following union function evaluate?

My guess is:

assuming `val iSet1 = new NonEmpty(2, 1, 3)` and `val iSet2 = new NonEmpty(5, 3 ,6)`...

`iSet1.union(iSet2)` would evaluate like:

1. `((1, Empty, Empty) union (3, Empty, Empty)) union (5, 3, 6).incl(2)`
2. `((1, Empty, Empty) union (3, Empty, Empty)) union (5, (3, 2, N), 6)`
3. `(Empty union Empty) union (5, (3, 2, N), 6) incl 1`
4. `Empty union (5, (3, (2, 1, N), N), 6)`

// 3 already exists so include simply returns true

5. `(Empty union Empty) (5, (3, (2, 1, N), N), 6) incl 3`

A more eye-friendly representation of 5 is:

```
                  5
                 / \
                3  6  
               / 
              2 
             /
            1
```

Are my evaluation steps correct?

If yes, in terms of "intuition" of why this works... is the general idea that `left union right` will eventually return `other` (since we will eventually recurse to an `Empty` IntSet) while the `element` of this "leaf" node will be added as part of `incl elem`?

My brain is having a hard time with this recursion stuff - really trying to build intuition.

Note: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489576/binary-trees-scala-recursion-for-the-union-of-trees) is referring to the same union function (from Martin's course) but I had a difficult time interpreting the diagram and evaluation given so I posted a more simple example with some good ole' asci art.

Comment: your step 1 is a bit wrong, it should be `(((1, Empty, Empty) union (3, Empty, Empty)) union (5, 3, 6)).incl(2)` (incl should be eval-ed last)